# Magento 2 admin add new review redirecting to review grid

Tags: admin, magento2.4, grid, review, magento2.4.5p1

We are using Magento 2.4.5-p1 version.

When we click on **New Review** button -

[image]

Then it is redirecting to the review grid -

[image]

This issue is also present on GitHub but no proper answer and this commit - https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/38cf8d61b3cca8d7e522f92601feccafbb0107b6 is not working,that code changes are already in that version.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug it's Magento default functionality.
when you click on the **New Review** button it will show a list of product grids. you can fetch any product and add reviews on it and check the frontend side